# Swipe gesture does't work when i add more items

Tags: ios, swift, swipe-gesture

In my app I use `swipe gesture` but when I add more items my app crashes and swipe gesture doesn't work. I don't know what to do. In my view controller I have

```
class controller: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource {

var array = [AnyObject]()

var check = false

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    var rightButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "edit"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "editClicked")

    self.editing = !self.editing

    rightButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

    var leftButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "settings"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "settingsClicked")

    leftButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomCell

    let object = array[indexPath.row] as! NSString

    cell.editCell(object, delete: check)

    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "deleteClicked", forControlEvents : UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

here is the function I use to add items

```
func addClicked () {

    check = true

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "add", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in textField.text = ""

    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "confirm", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        let textField = (alert.textFields![0] as! UITextField).text as String

        if textField != "" {

            self.array.insert(textField, atIndex: 0)

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }

    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {

        (ACTION) -> Void in

    }))

   self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var toBuy: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var atHome: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    var gesture, check: Bool!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
        var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))

        leftSwipe.direction = .Left
        rightSwipe.direction = .Right

        self.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

        gesture = false;
        check = false
    }


    func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        if (gesture == false) && (check == true){

            if (sender.direction == .Left) {

                gesture = true;

                var labelPosition = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x - 55.0, self.view.frame.origin.y);

                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

                    self.view.frame = CGRectMake( labelPosition.x , labelPosition.y , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

                }, completion: { (value: Bool) in

                    self.gesture = false;

                })
            }

            if (sender.direction == .Right) {

                gesture = true;

                var viewPosition = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + 55.0, self.view.frame.origin.y);

                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

                    self.view.frame = CGRectMake( viewPosition.x , viewPosition.y , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

                }, completion: { (value: Bool) in

                    self.gesture = false;

                })
            }

        }
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see MVC violation in your code. Please add the Swipe gesture handlers to your controller instead of your View(i.e) your Custom cell.

thus handlesSwipeMethod will move to "controller"

Comment: my app works there is no problem if you add 5-10 items. But when you add more than 10 it crashes

Comment: @compbealov: I understand that but as per me the correct approach is MVC